# How to add a drop down list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to add a drop down list of Profit margin figures (namely 8.5%, 10% and 12.5%) against each inventory item as shown below but I can't find out how to do it

```
Code    Product            Cost         Margin        GST     Customer Price

2345td  Bicycle Boy       $125.50   <drop down here>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you need a drop-down list with 3 options

If so, the functionality you're looking for is **data validation**

Directions for implementation in the following link are much better than anything I'd type here.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-dropdown-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b

Comment: Thanks Petr, I have manage to insert Drop down list and when press tab, three profit margins are there.

Comment: Did this provide the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I want to calculate GST based upon the (cost*margin)/Gst 10% from either of the 3 options.  3 options are  8.5%, 10% and 12.5%.